# Mounted variables not showing in next files (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, instance, render, vuejs3

**Hello**,
I have this code in my Vue3 App.

**main.js:**

```js
import App from './App.vue';

const app = createApp({
              data: () => {
                return {
                  message: "Hello";
                }
              },
              render: () => (
                h(App);
              )
            });
```

But app when mounted write me this error when i using {{ message }} in views/Home.vue

> Property "message" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.

How fix thats?

Comment: cann you add your `app.vue` code?